# Cant ping or ssh into RPI

Tags: ssh

i'm setting up a rpi.
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGx2n7rkfr8
It is in german but by watching u can see what he is doing. So i followed by installing the Raspberry OS onto my SDcard. Then i added the ssh file exactly like he did. This tutorial has worked before so i don't think that there is any problem, but just so u know what i did.
So i wanted to ssh into my pi by entering "ssh pi@"myip" into command prompt(i'm on windows).
The ip address should be right, as i looked that up in my router. (I have a fritzbox 7360)
When i do that i get the message "Connection timed out". Its trying to connect via host 22 if that matters :)
So yeah i dont really know where the problem is, it worked until i formatted the SD and put a new OS on it. I also deleted the RPi out of my Router and connected it new.
Does anybode have an idea what could be the issue or how i can solve it?
Thank u very much!

Comment: Try the 64 bit OS (select from pi imager)

Answer (score 0):

Before actually being able to SSH into your Pi, you must first enable the service in the Pi configuration.

I think the first step in the following link will best illustrate how to do that (step by step guide with images)
https://itsfoss.com/ssh-into-raspberry/

Also, you should check that the pi is properly connected to the network (ping to its IP from another device on the network, or check the router's connected clients).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: First of all thank u for your answer, i  will look into the article u sent. Still cant ping my pi from my laptop, even tho it is connected to my router...

Comment: You're getting closer. Now you know why you couldn't SSH into your device and what you need to fix. How did you connect your pi to the local network? Via WiFi or Ethernet cable? You should check the network settings. Also, you need to know if there are any particularities to your network (gateway, static IP, etc).